# Java Swing: Getting values from dynamically generated jTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, components

I have one tab by default (tab1)
New tabs are generated , equal to 'No of rooms'.
The dynamically generated tabs have same structure as of the default tab.
I don't know the name of textfields of newly generated tabs. 
How can I find the name of jtexfields generated on tab at run time so I can use .getText()

I cant use images to explain my problem unless I have 10 rep.
SO I am posting link from Daniweb I am not sure if this is allowed or not.

**Sorry I forgot to add the code**

```
   int no_room = Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText());
   for(int i = 1 ; i<no_room; i++)
   {
   int c = jTabbedPane5.getTabCount();
   jTabbedPane5.addTab("tab "+(i+1), jTabbedPane5.getTabComponentAt(c-1));
   jTabbedPane5.validate();
   jTabbedPane5.repaint();
   }
```

**EDIT 2: More Details**

I am building a desktop app 'Builder app'.

In there I ask client how many rooms he want in his house.
He says, for example 3 rooms.
Now at run time I generate 3 tabs (using the code above) for entering details of each room.
Each newly generated tab is exact copy of my 'default tab'.
 
Tabs consists of four textfields, now as with many other amateurs I have no idea how to retrieve values from these dynamically generated Textfields.
So here I am asking you to help me by telling me how can I use the .getText() method with these dynamically generated textfields , when I don't know their names.

I have seen similar questions but none has used tabs.

http://static.daniweb.com/images/attachments/3/ebbc1e39377be620031e5fe5d93f7940.jpg
http://static.daniweb.com/images/attachments/3/9577a07941c9116964dcb07c32a702c4.jpg
http://static.daniweb.com/images/attachments/3/97e62dfd97cb0230dad2e2df9783b935.jpg

Comment: Can you give us some code of the generated tabs?

Comment: You don't give enough information so that this question can be answered without wildly guessing. Please fix this deficiency.

Comment: Also, have you cross-posted the same question elsewhere, such as in Daniweb? If so, we greatly appreciate seeing links to cross-posts. If you ever volunteer to help here, you'll understand how frustrating it can be to spend quite a bit of time answering a question that has already been answered elsewhere.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels 

I cant post images unless I earn 10 rep (tx to the -1 s) , so I have to post my question at Daniweb, just for the sake of images.
The images you are seeing here are the links from Daniweb.

Comment: @johnchen902 sorry I forgot to add the code, I have added it now.

Comment: from this code isn't possible to simulating your issue, we aren't here to simulating, guessing, speculating,

Comment: Good God, in pursuit of trying to explain my problem as clearly as possible I even posted images.

Comment: Generate 2 tabs as you did. Fill up the first tab (form), and fill up the second with different area, doors and windows. Now go back to the first tab, I guessed you can found all you ordinarily filled up is missing. Am I right?

Comment: [crossposted](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/456751/java-swing-getting-values-from-dynamically-generated-jtabbedpane)

Comment: @johnchen902 yes, if I write 100 in area and 2 in door in first tab, same data appears in second tab. But when I change the area and door to 200 and 5 respectively in second tab, the data I entered in first tab has been replaced by this new data.

Comment: @Batman: that's because you're not creating new objects. Please see answer below. If you need more specific help, your best bet again is to show us compilable and runnable code. We don't want to see your whole program, especially if it's large, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem, in other words, an SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example). For more info on SSCCEs please look here: [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes you pointed out right. I need to generate new tabs dynamically, but the code I am using is **just copying** the tabs and hence its content.

Comment: @Batman: well, don't do that. Again, for better help, create and post an sscce.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ok I will first learn how to generate tabs, then I will ask for your help again If needed.
And thanks for detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Getting values from dynamically generated jTabbedPane

I think that one way to approach your problem is not to think in terms of adding new tabs to a JTabbedPane and instead think of creating and adding new objects to your program. Please consider the following suggestions:

- Create a class that creates the JPanel that is held and displayed by each tab of the JTabbedPane. For discussion purposes, let's call the class RoomDetailPanel
- When you create a new tab, do so, and then give it a new RoomDetailPanel object to display.
- Create a class that holds the JTabbedPane and which is responsible for creating the tabs and the RoomDetailPanel objects. For discussion purposes, let's call this the ClientDetailPanel.
- Give the ClientDetailPanel a collection of RoomDetailPanels, perhaps an `ArrayList<RoomDetailPanel>`.
- Whenever a new tab and RoomDetailPanel object are created, add the RoomDetailPanel object to the above ArrayList.
- When you want to extract all of the information that has been entered by the user, use a for loop to iterate through the ArrayList, querying each RoomDetailPanel object for the information it contains.

> Good God, in pursuit of trying to explain my problem as clearly as possible I even posted images.

We're frustrated because even with your code snippet and your images, we still can't suss exactly where you may be stuck. This is why we are continually asking for more information and clarification and which is why I can give you general overall advice, but cannot give you specific code advice. In the future, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) to give us this greater appreciation and understanding of your problem.

---

**Edit**

I wonder if a JTable would make for a cleaner interface?